# LinkedList Error? in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So Im trying to find the node with least value and make it at the end of the List. I got two functions trying to find out multiple ways of implementing it. but the list prints out unchanged.

Any Help would be appreciated.

My Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node * linkk;
typedef struct struct_list * list;

struct node {
    int item;
    linkk next;
};

int ConnectSmallElementToLast(linkk A);
int Connect(linkk A);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    linkk t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    linkk head = t;


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        t->item = i;
        t->next = malloc(sizeof(*t));
        t = t->next;
    }

     connect(t);

    for ( int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",head->item);
        head = head->next;
    }





    return 0;
}

int ConnectSmallElementToLast( linkk A)
{
    linkk L = A;
    linkk head = A;
    linkk printhead = L;
    linkk smallestNode = NULL;
    linkk pre = NULL;
    linkk post = NULL;
    int count=1, Number;
    Number = L->item;
    L = L->next;
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(L);i++)
    {
        if(Number > L->item)
        {
            Number == L->item;
            smallestNode = L;
            post = L->next;
            L = L->next;
            count++;
        }
        else{L = L->next;}
    }
    L->next = smallestNode;
    for (int i = 0; i< sizeof(head);i++)
    {
        if ( i == (count-1))
        {
            head->next = post;
        }else if( head->next == NULL)
        {
            head->next = smallestNode;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(printhead);i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",printhead->item);
        printhead = printhead->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

int Connect(linkk A)
{
    linkk L = A;
    linkk pre = NULL;
    linkk post = NULL;
    linkk current = NULL;
    linkk head = L;
    int smallest;
    int NumberPre,NumberCur,NumberPost;
    while (L != NULL && L->next !=NULL && L!=NULL)
    {
        pre = L;
        current = L->next;
        post = L->next->next;
        NumberPre = pre->item;
        NumberCur = L->next->item;
        NumberPost = L->next->next->item;
        if ( NumberCur < NumberPre && NumberCur < NumberPost )
        {
            pre->next = post;
            smallest = NumberCur;

        }else if(NumberPre < NumberCur && NumberPre < NumberPost)
        {
            L = current;
            smallest = NumberPre;
        }
        pre = pre->next;
        current = current->next;
        post = post->next;

    }
    for ( int i = 0; i<sizeof(head);i++)
    {
        if (head->next == NULL)
        {
            head->next->item = smallest;
            head->next->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t->next = malloc(sizeof(*t));` : `next` of the last element  must be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, your code is very strange to implement a linked list. try to google how other people use linked list.

From your code:

```
linkk t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
linkk head = t;


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    t->item = i;
    t->next = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    t = t->next;
}
```

it creates a linked list with head and 10 nodes in the list.

In your connect methods:

```
for ( int i = 0; i<sizeof(head);i++)
{
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        head->next->item = smallest;
        head->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

sizeof(head) is sizeof(linkk) which is a pointer to a node.
well, it is always 4 bytes in 32-bits system.

This explains why the loop fails.

Besides, you need to malloc a memory to the node before assign to the list.
Just like what you did in the for loop in main().

One more thing, people usually use a 'create' function to wrap all those thing need to do when creating node.

eg. 
1.allocating memory
2.assign value
3.put it into the list